# javascript filter method doesn't work with getElementsByName

Tags: javascript

Why the following code doesn't work (alert is not executed)? `custom_table` is some file upload fields in html, its length is 10.

```
var custom_table=document.getElementsByName('custom_table');
var result = custom_table.filter( function (x)  { return x.value });
alert(result.length);
```

If I replace `custom_table` with `names` in the following code, it works fine.

```
var names = new Array();
var object = { name : "Joe", value:20, email: "joe@hotmail.com"};

names.push(object);
object = { name : "Mike", value:50, email: "mike@hotmail.com"};
names.push(object);
object = { name : "Joe", value:45, email: "mike@hotmail.com"};
names.push(object);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an `HTMLCollection`*, which is not an array. `filter()` is only on arrays. You can dump it into an array easily enough:

```
var elementCollection = document.getElementsByName('myname');
var elementArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elementCollection, 0);
elementArray.filter(...); // this will now work
```

*or a `NodeList`, depending on the browser, the distinction isn't very important though

Comment: You can do that in one step. No need to `Array.prototype.slice()` then `.filter()`. Just `Array.prototype.filter.call(elemColl...`

Comment: Thank you for your nice example and great explanation! And cookie monster's solution also works.

Comment: @cookiemonster that's a good point, if `slice` works, then it makes sense other array methods will.

Answer (score 3):

The return value from `getElementsByName` is not a JavaScript array. You can copy the contents into one, however:

```
var custom_table=document.getElementsByName('custom_table');
custom_table = [].slice.call(custom_table, 0);
```

Then `.filter`, `.map`, etc. will work.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is also correct, but I can only mark the first one as final answer. Sorry.

Comment: Pointy's answer came a bit before mine, if you want to award him the checkmark.